# Keep shopping cart items in cache ro database

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart

I am developing on ASP.NET e-Shop software .
Which one is right ?

- Keeping user shopping cart items in cache with an expire time
- Keeping user shopping cart items in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong... all depends on your requirements regarding scalability, performance etc.

IF you design for really high performance I would cache those in-memory (i.e. write-through cache) but also persist them into DB with an expire time... if data loss is no problem then you can wait with persisting till user finishes the order...

Answer (score 1):

It depends, Ideally  "Keeping user shopping cart items in cache with an expire time" is best, **because Agreed rule for shopping cart is** *"Items stored in your cart for 7 days or at max 10 days"*

If you want store it permanently until customer clears the cart, **then store it into database**

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use database to store the data.

Because, normally shopping cart will be redirected to a third party site like `Paypal` to complete the payment part the final stage.

In here you may encounter problem of passing session variables.

I think you can use `SQL Server` to store the `Sessions`. Please look at this article about [Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).

Hope this helps